# Unable to capture node-to-node traffic in a wireless access point

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, wireshark, tshark

I have created a wireless access point on ubuntu and I have written a program that parses network traffic obtained via tshark and condenses it into a readable form. I am able to capture traffic going to and from the internet. Now i have three nodes on my network:

**Node A**: The wireless access point running tshark
**Node B**: Computer 1
**Node C**: Computer 2

To create TCP traffic in my network, i used nmap on Node A to scan Node B but i am unable to capture that traffic. Any clue how to do that?

I tried putting my network interface card in promiscuous mode but that didn't help.

Comment: Do you see any traffic at all on tshark?

Comment: @user1794469 yeah when i send and receive traffic via the internet.